# how to find the date for the 3rd day from the current date iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, datetime

Can any one tell that how  to find the date for the 3rd day from the current date iphone/ipad.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Sample Code

```
    NSDate  * currentDate=[NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval interval=[currentDate timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval intervalForThirdDate=interval+86400*3;
NSDate *nextDate=[[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:intervalForThirdDate];
```

Comment: I'm not sure that multiplying the interval by 86400 is what you mean; that'll be a date 86400 times as long after 1970 as the current date.

Comment: As far as I can see he/she is not doing that, is he? He is adding 86400*3 to interval. Still the example seems a bit convoluted for the approach he is taking.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setDay:3];
NSDate *threeDaysFromToday = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:today options:0];
```

Slightly modified example from [Apple's own documentation on NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW3). Check the link out for further info and more examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval threeDays = 86400*3;

NSDate *threeDaysFromToday = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:threeDays sinceDate:today];
```

Comment: Should be used carefully around daylight savings time.

Comment: thanks Christo ,your answer is some what static so i have tried this sample from the post of Louis Gerbarg - in the following url = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172698/how-do-i-get-the-next-and-earlier-date-of-the-current-date-in-iphone-sdk Thanks Cristo

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
// get the gregorian calendar ready to go; use the getter for the current system
// calendar if you're happy to deal with other calendars too
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                                initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];

// get an NSDate object that is three days in the future
NSDate *dateInFuture = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3*24*60*60];

// grab the date components for the bits we want to print in this example
NSDateComponents *componentsOfDateInFuture = 
       [gregorianCalendar
        components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit
          fromDate:dateInFuture];

// and print
NSLog(@"in three days it'll be %04d/%02d/%02d", 
           componentsOfDateInFuture.year,
           componentsOfDateInFuture.month, 
           componentsOfDateInFuture.day);

// clean up
[gregorianCalendar release];
```

EDIT: Pablo Santa Cruz's answer is better for ensuring you're three days in the future, given daylight savings concerns. This is how you'd decompose an NSDate to day/month/year though, for the purposes of having the date rather than simply an NSDate.

Answer (score 0):

choose one:

```
NSDate *futureDate;
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[components setDay:3];
futureDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [NSDate date], futureDate);



NSDate *futureDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:3 * (24*60*60)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:86400*3]
```

But as someone mentioned above, DST might make this too inaccurate. Depends on how important that is.